# Database connection problem in ofbiz framework

Tags: java, ofbiz

Hello I'm using ofbiz framework. I completed all set up of framework and trying to connect to database but i am getting an error as

> Could not get next sequenced ID for sequence name: Visit

Comment: Hi Pravallika, Can you elaborate more? Which version you are using and what setting have you done yet?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file `entityengine.xml`

See which database is set as default and whether you have given the correct `DB URL`, `username`, `password` etc